# Custom alignment in richText cells Exceljs

Tags: javascript, exceljs

> "exceljs": "^3.9.0"

I need to create a spreadsheet with cells that have 2 different values that looks like this.
First value needs to be aligned left and second value needs to be aligned right.
[image]

My result right now is:
[image]

Here is my richText for the cells without "/"

```
    [
  {
    "font": {
      "size": 8,
      "name": "Arial"
    },
    "alignment": {
      "vertical": "middle",
      "horizontal": "distributed"
    },
    "text": "392.3 "
  },
  {
    "font": {
      "color": {
        "argb": "00c90a00"
      },
      "size": 8,
      "name": "Arial"
    },
    "alignment": {
      "vertical": "middle",
      "horizontal": "distributed"
    },
    "text": " -10%"
  }
]
```

And richText for cell with "/"

```
    [
  {
    "font": {
      "size": 8,
      "name": "Arial"
    },
    "alignment": {
      "vertical": "middle",
      "horizontal": "distributed"
    },
    "text": "392.3 "
  },
  {
    "font": {
      "size": 8,
      "name": "Arial"
    },
    "alignment": {
      "vertical": "middle",
      "horizontal": "distributed"
    },
    "text": " / "
  },
  {
    "font": {
      "color": {
        "argb": "00c90a00"
      },
      "size": 8,
      "name": "Arial"
    },
    "alignment": {
      "vertical": "middle",
      "horizontal": "distributed"
    },
    "text": " -10%"
  }
]
```

Is it possible to do what the first screenshot looks like?

Comment: You can't have two different alignments in the same cell. You would need to create two separate cells and specify different alignments for each.

Comment: @jdaz comment is correct. Once you have the two columns you can style it so it looks like one cell.

Comment: do you know how to create 2 cells in a single column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to do what the first screenshot looks like?

Yes, that is possible, though you're not able to align text differently in the same cell. It isn't doable with Excel itself and thus definitely not with ExcelJS! There are hundreds of articles asking the question about Excel, but one quote hits the nail on it's head:

> Unlike Word, Excel does not have the concept of paragraphs within a cell. Horizontal and vertical alignment apply to a cell as a whole.

*Quote taken from the User [Hansv MVP](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/profile/f3db0141-453f-4468-8422-58efbe88bd6b) from [this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other-mso_2007/multiple-text-alignments-in-a-single-cell-excel/a9dd3149-fc14-49c1-805c-923b33b7fe27).*

You can approach the project via different roads, depending on which suits you the most:

- [Split the cells](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/merge-or-split-cells-in-a-table-8b458deb-0fc5-4c8d-8d94-2d4da98193f8) with the data. ExcelJS does has the [`.spliceRows()` function](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs#splice), so you could use that (*with RichText formatting on respective cells*).
- You could implement the logic for writing from the get-go, i.e. implement one part of the data in one cell, the next part in the cell after that and so on. Afterwards you're able [to color the border](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs#borders) to the neighboring data to your background color, thus vanishing it.
- *etc.*

I highly suggest the second approach. In my opinion it should be the easiest solution as you can properly set up a "formatting logic" in the sense of being free with each values you're writing.

Comment: @texas697 I hope this helped you! Let me know in case there was anything unclear :-)

Comment: yes! thank you. I went back and used the merge cells method. works great!